# Importar um .java em outro .java

Tags: java, importação

Tenho 2 códigos:

Código 1:

```
class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args){

Pessoas pessoa1 = new Pessoas();
pessoa1.idade = 1;
pessoa1.nascimento = 2;
pessoa1.altura = 0.5;
pessoa1.nome = "texto";


}
}
```

Código 2:

```
class Pessoas {

int idade;
int nascimento;
double altura;
String nome;

public static void main(String[] args){


}
}
```

Já tentei usar o `package` e `import`, porém não funcionou. Acho que usei eles errados. Como eu uso eles para usar o código 2 no código 1?

OBS: Os dois códigos estão na mesma pasta.

Comment: Sim os 2 códigos estão na mesma pasta e preciso que o código 1 acesse o código 2 para criar os dados da pessoa1

Comment: Funcionou normalmente comigo.

Comment: aqui da erro falando que `Pessoas pessoa1 = new Pessoas();` diz que não e possível encontrar o simbulo Pessoas

Comment: Então você não está colocando as duas no mesmo package.

Comment: os 2 estão na mesma pasta e o código esta extamente como eu coloquei no post

Comment: Como eu disse, simulei aqui e não deu nada, esse erro ocorre quando uma classe não é oncontrada. Se as duas estivessem no mesmo pacote, não daria este erro.

Comment: como eu boto as 2 no mesmo package? para ver se esse erro some

Comment: Se estiver usando eclipse ou netbeans, é só arrastar a classe para o mesmo pacote que a outra estiver.

Comment: não usso nenhum dos 2 crio os código usando Notpad++, não consigo usar nenhum dos 2

Comment: Sem ide, basta colocar os arquivos na mesma pasta.

Comment: então eu to usando na mesma pasta porem no cmd fala que `Pessoas pessoa1 = new Pessoas();`não e possível encontrar o sinbulo Pessoas

Comment: Bom, então não sei como te ajudar. Pois simulei criando na ide, depois criando manualmente no notepad e cmd, e nas duas formas funcionou normalmente aqui. O problema está em outro procedimento que você está fazendo.

Comment: Que comando você está usando para compilar esses arquivos?

Comment: javac "nome do arquivo".java

Comment: @ClockWork Você está compilando qual arquivo primeiro?

Comment: Coloque o código inteiro, incluindo os imports.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida por incrivel que pareça, o código é só isso mesmo, não tem imports. Se salvar os dois, roda normal, acredito que essa pergunta é um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/28595).

Comment: @ClockWork Coloque o comando exato que está a utilizar para compilar. Se tem mais de 1 classe a compilar tem de compilar todas, fazendo por exemplo `javac *.java`

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que compilar o código assim:

```
javac Principal.java Pessoas.java
```

Depois, para rodar, faça isso:

```
java Principal
```

É muito importante ter os dois arquivos na linha de comando do `javac`, caso contrário, ele não irá compilar.

Answer (score 0):

Se ambas estão na mesma pasta, então deveriam estar no mesmo pacote(acesso default como você declarou a classe)

Experimente colocar em pastas diferentes e declarar ambas classes como "public class"

Comment: O fato de não terem o modificador public também não ocasiona o erro. Experimenta criar os dois arquivos sem public e compilar pra você ver. Minha conclusão é que, após testar os códigos do autor da pergunta, o problema não tem nada a ver com nenhum dos códigos.

Comment: Verdade, até tava pensando, só daria problema mesmo caso as duas classes fossem default e estivessem em pacotes diferentes, aí não teria visibilidade, mas acho que não é o caso mesmo.

Answer (score -2):

Na classe 2, não se deve ter um método main, mas sim um construtor:

```
public Pessoas(){
}
```

Já na classe 1, utilize, acima da classe:

```
import Pessoas;
```

Comment: Ainda Retorna class1.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
Pessoas pessoa1 = new Pessoas();

Comment: Creio que isso não tem nada a ver com o problema. O código funciona normalmente sem o construtor. Qualquer classe não abstrata é instanciavel sem ter um construtor explicito declarado

Comment: Olha, não há nenhum impedimento em ter várias funções `main` em um projeto Java... Sem falar que está no mesmo pacote portanto [não precisa de importação explícita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248750/64969). E como o @Articuno falou, o construtor padrão não tem nada a ver